# redirects the page even if the select box is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form where I am using two select box. The problem is, it redirects the page when I click on submit button showing the required field message. I want to stop the redirection on click of proceed button if the select values are empty and show the normal required field message. I tried using e.preventDefault(); also but it still redirects. Below is the code:

HTML CODE:

```
<select class="form-control input_wrap" name="answer[31]" id="property" required/>
    <option value="">Select property type</option>
    <option value="Independent House">Independent House</option>
    <option value="Villa">Villa</option>
    <option value="Individual Flat">Individual Flat</option>
    <option value="Plot or Land">Plot or Land</option>
</select>

<select class="form-control input_wrap" name="answer[42]" id="jurisdiction" onchange='CheckColors();' required />
    <option value="">Select Jurisdiction</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="Others">Others</option>
</select>


<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default proceed_btn">Proceed</button>
```

JS CODE:

```
$('.proceed_btn').bind('click',function(e){
    // e.preventDefault();
    // e.stopPropagation();
    $(".select_wrap").bind('click', function(){
        if($("#property").val()==""){
            return false;
        }
        if($("#jurisdiction").val()==""){
            return false;
        }
    })
 })
```

Please suggest any solution for this problem.

Comment: write your code in function and call it in  <form onsubmit="return function()">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please check if this help~

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

          $('.proceed_btn').bind('click', function(e) {

              // e.preventDefault();
              // e.stopPropagation();
              if ($("#property").val() == "") {
                  alert('Display what you want to say!!');
                  return false;
              }
              if ($("#jurisdiction").val() == "") {
                  alert('Display what you want to say!!');
                  return false;
              }
              alert('Ready to go~');

          });
      });
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. I have done the same way :)

Answer (score 0):

Hey you should be doing the validation at the form level and then should be redirecting.
Example:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>

    <p>When you submit the form, a function is triggered which alerts some text.</p>

    <form action="demo_form.asp" onsubmit="return myFunction()">
      Enter name: <input type="text" name="fname">
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

    <script>
    function myFunction() {
        alert("The form was submitted");
        return false;
    }
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

So `onsubmit` you can validate the form and then return true if everything is fine. or else so error in a select option and return false.

Comment: is there any other way?? apart from this??

Answer (score 0):

You can not use button tag with type submit because submit is also submit your form and you are try

```
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default proceed_btn">Proceed
```

You can use like this

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default proceed_btn">Proceed</button>
```

or

```
 <input type="button" class="btn btn-default proceed_btn" value="Proceed">
```

Comment: forgot to close the tag I am using that way only

Comment: You are also use type="submit" that is the problem

Comment: use type="button" instedof submit  if you want click event

Comment: I found the solution to my answer... I used if else condition individually in proceed button it's working fine now. Thank you.